# ASP.NET MVC3 - Most Appropriate Way to Store IsAdmin information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 application i have two types of users - regular users and admin users. Obviously the latter have greater privileges than the former. I have a page level authorization implementation in place, but for screen level items (show this button if admin, etc.) I would like to know what is the most appropriate solution to make a boolean IsAdmin flag available on all screens. I can think of a bunch of different methods cookies/session variables/httpcontext, but I'm wondering what is used with success in production. Any guidance is appreciated

Thanks in advance

JP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx

`HttpContext.User` is of type `IPrincipal`, which has one method `IsInRole`. If you are using `FormsAuthentication` you'll get this for free. `HttpContext.User` will be available directly from any view

Answer (score 0):

The ViewBag seems an easy fit.

```
ViewBag.UserIsAdmin = somevalue;
```

That's available to every view and is meant to be used for View data that isn't part of the model.

The only downside is that you need to populate it every request on views that need it, but you can actually do that in a Base controller's Initialization method if it's a global thing.

As for how to store it between requests, not cookies. Those are easily forgable. You can use a session to store it between requests, or you can simply repopulate it every request if it's a fast request (and you can't use sessions) in your Base controller.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Session, because you have to check whether it is timeout or not. It's hard to code in many places (my experience).

You can use Form Authentication that leveraged by ASP.NET membership. Then you can safely use HttpContext.User.Identity to check user privilege